# How do I bind web service to a particular glassfish port?

Tags: web-services, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have `Glassfish 3.1.1 (Metro JAX-WS stack)` installation with several http listeners in my domain's virtual server. 
When I deploy my EAR, web application and soap services are all bound to all available http listeners whereas I want them to be held by different listeners, each having it's own performance and connection pool setup.

I believed that `sun-web.xml` should be responsible for that sort of binding but I haven't found any options of binding service to specific port or virtual server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `deploy` command with an accordingly set `virtualservers` commandline parameter... for reference see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/deploy-1.html or page 262 etc. at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/pdf/821-2433.pdf

Another option:

Several config files have new names (for example `glassfish-web.xml` is the new name for `sun-web.xml`).

To bind your EAR to specific URI see esp. the `web` element and its sub-element like `web-uri` - for details and samples see

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaqk.html#scrolltoc
- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaql.html
- http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/10/glassfish-webxml-and-sun-webxml.html