# External WSDL in BPEL Module: Address already in use 8080

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, glassfish, bpel

I added External WSDL(s) to my BPEL Module which are on localhost:8080 which is used by GlassFish 4. I have GlassFish v2.x running for HTTP on localhost:52059. GF2 and GF4 are on separate domains. They both work fine. However, when I deploy my Composite Application that uses a BPEL Module which references external WSDL(s) on localhost:8080, I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Successful execution of Start: RetailerBPELModuleCA
WARNING: (JBIMA0405) Start of service assembly RetailerBPELModuleCA succeeded partially; some service units failed to start.
    * Component: sun-http-binding
      ERROR: (SOAPBC_START_1) HTTPBC-E00205: Start failed. java.lang.Exception: LifecycleException:  PWC3985: Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: 8080
    * Component: sun-bpel-engine
      INFO: (JBIMA0409) Lifecycle operation start succeeded for Service Unit RetailerBPELModuleCA-RetailerBPELModule.
Cleaning up...
[stop-service-assembly]
    Stopping a service assembly...
        host=localhost
        port=5000
        name=RetailerBPELModuleCA
[shutdown-service-assembly]
    Shutting down a service assembly...
        host=localhost
        port=5000
        name=RetailerBPELModuleCA
[undeploy-service-assembly]
    Undeploying a service assembly...
        host=localhost
        port=5000
        name=RetailerBPELModuleCA
```

Any idea what it could be?

This only happens for Composite Applications using BPEL Modules with external WSDL(s). How come?

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace indicates that the BPEL module wants to start a service listening on port 8080 (probably the webservice stuff), which is in use by Glassfish as you described.

To fix this you can either change the port of Glassfish or the one of the `sun-http-binding` component.

I don't know how you can configure the BPEL module but the [Oracle docs about HTTP Binding Component Runtime Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/821-0015/cnfg_http-bc-runtime-parameters_r/index.html) shows that you might be able to configure the port via NetBeans.

**See also:**

- [How do I bind web service to a particular glassfish port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298743/how-do-i-bind-web-service-to-a-particular-glassfish-port)
- [How to run glassfish 4 on port 80 instead of 8080. root acess is not an issue.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045897/how-to-run-glassfish-4-on-port-80-instead-of-8080-root-acess-is-not-an-issue)

Comment: I set the HTTP port for the sun-http-binding to 9080. It was set to -1 previously. Unfortunately, the same error message persists.

Comment: Did you try to change the Glassfish port?

Comment: I changed the Glassfish 4 ports to 7071 for admin, 7070 for http, 7072 for https. Now I'm getting "Address already in use: 7070". Doing "lsof -i :7070" on terminal says 7070 is used by  *:arcp (LISTEN)

Comment: My Glassfish 2 ports are 5000 - admin, 52059 - http, and 52058 - https. However, when I start Glassfish 2, it seems like its taking over 7070 or 8080, whatever Glassfish 4's HTTP is set to.